# How to fade a bootstrap modal in using custom javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap css, but not the javascript (as I'm using Angular2).

I have a modal with the standard bootstrap markup:

```
<div
  [ngClass]="{'in': viewModel.visible}"
  class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
```

The problem is if I set .modal to display block it abruptly shows immediately (doesn't fade in). I need to replicate the bootstrap fade in sequence, without using jquery, how can I do this?

Comment: Why not just use CSS transitions? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: can you try adding the class `in` to the modal instead of setting it manually to block? then removing the `.in` should make it fade